# Python - How to check a element that should not exist in the page

Tags: python, validation, selenium, webdriver, assert

I use selenium webdriver, how can i check if the element should not be present in the page and I'm testing python. Can anyone suggest any solutions to this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this a number of ways. Lazy would be something like this.

```
# Import these at top of page
import unittest
try: assert '<div id="Waldo" class="waldo">Example</div>' not in driver.page_source
except AssertionError, e: self.verificationErrors.append("Waldo incorrectly appeared in page source.")
```

Or you could import Expected conditions and asserting it returns presence_of_element_located is not **T**rue. Notice true is caps sensitive and presence_of_element_located either returns True or Not Null so assertFalse wouldn't be an easier way to phrase this.

```
# Import these at top of page
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

try: assert EC.presence_of_element_located( (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Waldo"]') ) is not True
except AssertionError, e: self.verificationErrors.append('presence_of_element_located returned True for Waldo')
```

Or like Raj said, you could use find_element**s** and assert there are 0.

```
import unittest

waldos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('waldo')
try: self.assertEqual(len(waldos), 0)
except AssertionError, e: self.verificationErrors.append('Found ' + str(len(waldos)) + ' Waldi.')
```

You could also assert that a NoSuchElementException will occur.

```
# Import these at top of page
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try: 
    with self.assertRaises(NoSuchElementException) as cm:
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.waldo')
except AssertionError as e:
    raise e
```

Comment: What a kak answer though, horrible.

Answer (score 1):

yes try below its one liner and simple to use

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("yourXpath/your locator stratgey")).size() >0){
            // if size is greater then zero that means element
            // is present on the page
        }else if(!(driver.findElements(By.xpath("yourXpath/your locator stratgey")).size() >0)){
            // if size is smaller then zero that means
            // element is not present on the page
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try: 
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="should_not_exist"]')
    should_exist = False
except:
    should_exist = True

if not should_exist:
    // Do something
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create a method IsElementPresent which will return whether element is present on page or not. You can call this method in your test case.

```
public boolean IsElementPresent(String locator, String locatorvalue) 
{
    try 
    {   
        if(locator.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
        {
            driver.findElement(By.id(locatorvalue));                
        }
        return true;
        }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e) 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question was posted with a python tag and answer is for Java.

Comment: We don't want this horrible stuff on the `python` tag